# How do I keep merge in Git from overwriting all my master's changes since the branch was first created?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge-conflict

I create a branch, "test1," change a file, and do not merge it back in master.  I forget about the test for a week.  I made lots of changes in master since that test1 branch.

But, then I decide I still like that one feature in test1 that I did, a single file I changed.

When I merge the branch test1 into master, what gets merged?  Just the test1 file?  I don't want to overwrite all my new master files with the old test1 branch files (except that one file I changed).

Answer (score 2):

The default merge strategy, `recursive`, will find the common ancestor and
attempt to *apply the changes* that occurred in the `test1` branch to the current branch (i.e. `master`).  So the command `git merge test1` will preserve the changes that occurred in the `master` branch, and apply the one change that you performed on the `test` branch.

And fear not!  If things do somehow go awry (e.g. there is a conflict but you resolve it incorrectly) git makes it easy to reset a branch back to an earlier commit and try the merge again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to ensure you check out the branch you wish to merge into (the master branch in your case), and then run the git merge command.

```
git checkout master
git merge test1
```

Also check the 'Basic Merging' section on the official documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)